Her one concern was for the health of her baby


Her one concern was for the health of her baby. (from my dictionary)




Her one concern was the health of her baby.


Do we really need the 'for' in no.1 ? Why is there 'for' which is not in 2 ?
The 'for' here represents the direction of her concern?

Concern for is a perfectly normal expression - see Definition 6 here. Without for, I think the sentence implies that the baby's health was the only thing she thought about, rather than the only thing she was worried about.

That which we are concerned about is a concern of ours.

His only concern was (about) the timing of the event.

We can also be concerned for someone: their health, their safety, their happiness and well-being, etc.

His only concern was (for) their safety.

Since concern can mean "worry, preoccupation" or "responsibility", we can disambiguate by using the preposition when speaking of a worry or preoccupation, and omit the preposition when speaking of a responsibility.  But not all speakers perceive a nuanced difference there.

OP asked whether "for" is necessary in the first sentence:


Her one concern was for the health of her baby.
Her one concern was the health of her baby.


Answer: There is no difference in meaning between the two sentences.
In  modern grammar, there is a preference for conciseness, avoiding unnecessary prepositions when they do not add essential meaning.
In this case,  "for" is more common in traditional or formal styles, but its inclusion or omission does not significantly change the meaning.
Traditional grammar: The first sentence reflects a formal or traditional style, where prepositions like "for" are used to explicitly indicate direction, purpose, or relationship.
Modern grammar: The second sentence is more concise, omitting the preposition without losing clarity or meaning.
Both sentences convey the same core idea: her primary concern is her baby’s health. The difference lies more in style than in meaning. In many modern contexts, "for" might be considered unnecessary and therefore omitted.
When we learned grammar, we were often taught to use prepositions with certain verbs. However, in modern usage, omitting the preposition can be correct or stylistic, depending on the context:
Write to us → Write us.
Send to us → Send us

In school exams, prepositions are important. Especially in terms of these words: explain TO me, expound TO me, mention TO me, intimate TO me, insinuate TO me, etc.

English runs on prepositions.  "Listen me" is ungrammatical in standard English.
